# knockout observableArray remove causes errors and fails to remove

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have an issue that I have spent two days on trying to figure out, I will try to put everything here to explain the background without unnecessary information but please ask and I shall provide the info.

**The problem**

The process is, that the user selects the team they want to add to the competition, clicks add, the team selected will then be removed from the main `teams` list, and added to the `competition.teams` list. To remove a team, the user selects the team from the options box, and clicks remove. This will remove the team from the `competition.teams` array, and re-added to the `teams` array.

1. I have a list of "teams" in a drop down box, with a button to "add team". When clicked, it will add the team selected from the drop-down box to the select options box. When I remove the Team from the box, it will fail to remove it from the parent list that is data bound to the options box.
2. When the team is then readded, both entries in the select are the same team name.

**The desired outcome**

I want the code to work as described above, its possible I have over-engineered the solution due to my limited knowledge of knockout/javascript. I am open to other solutions, I havent got to the stage of submitting this back to the server yet, i predict this will not be as easy as a normal form submit!

**The exception**

The error in the chrome console is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>       at eval (eval at parseBindingsString (knockout-min.3.4.2.js:68), :3:151)
>       at f (knockout-min.3.4.2.js:94)
>       at knockout-min.3.4.2.js:96
>       at a.B.i (knockout-min.3.4.2.js:118)
>       at Function.Uc (knockout-min.3.4.2.js:52)
>       at Function.Vc (knockout-min.3.4.2.js:51)
>       at Function.U (knockout-min.3.4.2.js:51)
>       at Function.ec (knockout-min.3.4.2.js:50)
>       at Function.notifySubscribers (knockout-min.3.4.2.js:37)
>       at Function.ha (knockout-min.3.4.2.js:41)

**The Code**

[image: Teams Multi select and DropDown]

The HTML for the screenshot:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="selectedTeams" class="col-md-12">Select your Teams</label>
        <button type="button" data-bind="enable:$root.teams().length>0,click:$root.addTeam.bind($root)"
                class="btn btn-default col-md-12">Add Team</button>
        <button type="button" data-bind="enable:competition().teams().length>0,click:$root.removeTeam.bind($root)"
                class="btn btn-default col-md-12">Remove Team</button>
        <a data-bind="attr:{href:'/teams/create?returnUrl='+window.location.pathname+'/'+competition().id()}"class="btn btn-default">Create a new Team</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select id="teamSelectDropDown" data-bind="options:$root.teams(),optionsText:'name',value:teamToAdd,optionsCaption:'Select a Team to Add..'"
                class="dropdown form-control"></select>
        <select id="selectedTeams" name="Teams" class="form-control" size="5"
                data-bind="options:competition().teams(),optionsText:function(item){return item().name;},value:teamToRemove">
                </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `addTeam` button click code:

```
self.addTeam = function () {
    if ((self.teamToAdd() !== null) && (self.competition().teams().indexOf(self.teamToAdd()) < 0)){// Prevent blanks and duplicates
        self.competition().teams().push(self.teamToAdd);
        self.competition().teams.valueHasMutated();
    }
    self.teams.remove(self.teamToAdd());
    self.teamToAdd(null);
};
```

the `removeTeam` button click code:

```
self.removeTeam = function () {
    self.teams.push(self.teamToRemove());
    self.competition().teams.remove(self.teamToRemove());
    self.competition().teams.valueHasMutated();
    self.teamToRemove(null);
};
```

the `Competition` object (some properties removed for brevity):

```
function Competition(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    self.teams = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(data.teams, function (team) {
            return ko.observable(new Team(team));
        }));
};
```

the `team` object:

```
function Team(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
}
```

Anything missing or unclear? Please ask and I will add to the materials on the question.

### The Solution

*As suggested by @user3297291*

The problem was that the objects being added to `competition.teams` were observable in some places and not observable in others. This was causing a binding error in some places where it would try to access the observable property inside the observable object.

**Changed Competition Object**

```
function Competition(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
  self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
  self.teams = ko.observableArray(
    ko.utils.arrayMap(data.teams, function (team) {
      return new Team(team);
    }));
};
```

**Revised HTML binding (only simplified the `optionsText` binding)**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label for="selectedTeams" class="col-md-12">Select your Teams</label>
        <button type="button" data-bind="enable:$root.teams().length>0,click:$root.addTeam.bind($root)"
                class="btn btn-default col-md-12">Add Team</button>
        <button type="button" data-bind="enable:competition().teams().length>0,click:$root.removeTeam.bind($root)"
                class="btn btn-default col-md-12">Remove Team</button>
        <a data-bind="attr:{href:'/teams/create?returnUrl='+window.location.pathname+'/'+competition().id()}"class="btn btn-default">Create a new Team</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select id="teamSelectDropDown" data-bind="options:$root.teams(),optionsText:'name',value:teamToAdd,optionsCaption:'Select a Team to Add..'"
                class="dropdown form-control"></select>
        <select id="selectedTeams" name="Teams" class="form-control" size="5"
                data-bind="options:competition().teams(),optionsText:'name',value:teamToRemove">
                </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Revised Add Team function**

```
self.addTeam = function () {
    if ((self.teamToAdd() !== null) && (self.competition().teams().indexOf(self.teamToAdd()) < 0)){
        self.competition().teams().push(self.teamToAdd());
        self.competition().teams.valueHasMutated();
    }
    self.teams.remove(self.teamToAdd());
    self.teamToAdd(null);
};
```

**Revised Remove Team Function**

*pretty sure I don't need the `valueHasMutated()` call anymore but at least it works..*

```
self.removeTeam = function () {
    self.teams.push(self.teamToRemove());
    self.competition().teams.remove(self.teamToRemove());
    self.competition().teams.valueHasMutated();
    self.teamToRemove(null);
};
```

Comment: On your selected teams dropdown there is the following binding: `optionsText:function(item){return item().name;}`. This is a stab in the dark, but try removing the parentheses from item(). "Item" should already refer to the underlying object.

Comment: I think because it comes through as an observable, I had to call with parentheses, I will try though, I can't remember what happened when I piped it out to a function in JavaScript rather than in the HTML.

Comment: I guess the issue is that in the optionsText attribute, you are passing 'name' which is fine if it is a plane string. However, I can see that it is actually an observable in your viewModel which is why, knockout is throwing error as you are passing it a function instead of a string. I would suggest to remove those single quotes and add parentheses to name and try..

Comment: @gkb, I think you may be right, but when I changed the some of the HTML it comes back saying cannot read `id` of undefined... seems like theres a wider, deep rooted problem causing many issues, I shall certainly be trying to uncomplicate my code though, on raising the question it highlighted how over the top some bits were!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're filling an `observableArray` with `observable` instances. This is something you generally should **not** do:

```
// Don't do this:
self.teams = ko.observableArray(
  ko.utils.arrayMap(data.teams, function(team) {
    return ko.observable(new Team(team));
  })
);
```

Instead, include the `Team` instances without wrapping them:

```
// Do this instead:
self.teams = ko.observableArray(
  ko.utils.arrayMap(data.teams, function(team) {
    return new Team(team);
  })
);
```

Now, you can use the "simple" `optionsText` binding, like you did earlier:

```
data-bind="optionsText: 'name', /* ... */"
```

---

*Personal preference:* you don't need the `utils.arrayMap` helper when we have `.map` in every browser. I'd personally write:

```
Team.fromData = data => new Team(data);
// ...
self.teams = ko.observableArray(data.teams.map(Team.fromData));
```

Comment: perhaps slightly off topic, but I have not seen this fromData before.. sounds like something useful! Also, is there a reason behind not putting observables in observablearray? I can see I have probably over-thought/over-engineered the code horrifically, but I would like to learn for the future. Thanks for the tips, I shall try this out as soon as I get back home.

Comment: you sir, are a genius. The issue was kind of two fold.. it seems I was making it too complicated (as stated) with the observable in the observableArray. In addition, I had mismatched the objects, in some places i would add an observable to the collection, others a non-observable. With the objects corrected as you suggest (not including the mapping yet..), the code works, no errors being thrown and the team selection works well. Now to figure out the serialisation!